# Probability of search results showing up for two different merchants with different products in a top 25 list.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If we have 115,000 results for a given search term on a shopping web site with multiple merchants and one merchant has 28 products that match while the other has 78, what is the probability of their products showing up in the top 25 for any given search that matches?
My idea for a solution ignoring that each pick would deduct 1 from the total sum of product search results:

### Merchant 1:

Probability of one product showing up:
$$\frac{28}{115000}\times100 \approx 0.024$$
probability of it being in the top 25:
$$0.024 \times 25 = 0.60$$

### Merchant 2:

$$\frac{ 78 }{115000}\times100\approx0.068\\
0.068\times25\approx1.7$$
Probability of products for both merchants to show up in top 25:
$$0.006\times0.017\times100\approx0.01$$ 
Is this solution feasible?

Comment: See this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks, it was my firs post.

Comment: use `\cdot` and `\frac12` for "$\cdot$"(or "*")and "$\frac12$"

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to edit it, but you were faster.

Comment: I hope you would be able properly write up questions properly in the future :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it in a better way:
$$P=1-\dfrac{\binom{28}0\binom{78}0\binom{11500}{25}}{\binom{11500+28+78}{25}}$$Don't know if this probability same as yours?

Comment: I forgot to mention that in theory it is possible for multiple products of one merchant to show up in the first 25 products of the search results. The only products that would be blocked are the ones already contained in the list.

Comment: @user1288263 see the edit.

Comment: Assuming the 8 is supposed to be 28 and 11500 is 115000, I get 0.022771981%